# ggplot2: geom_text label on ordered geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I am having trouble plotting value labels over ordered bars on a ggplot bar chart (I believe it is related to the fact that I am reordering the bars based on their value). Assistance is greatly appreciated. A `dput()` sample of my data is below, as well as the code I am currently using & the associated error message. Apologies in advance for the long `dput()`

```
test<-structure(list(Area = c("East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", "West", "East", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West", "East", "West", "East", "West", "West", "East", "West"), OPReason = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B",     
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C",         
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C",   
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), Amount = c(825.68, 455.04, 347, 532, 323.2, 30.39, 557.58, 
281.89, 260, 574.77, 295.57, 536, 308.35, 681.46, 269.33, 0, 771, 803.4, 478.79, 
784.59, 310.5, 458.79, 281.14, 6861.51, 8261.71, 1725.06, 268, 1175.69, 1569.6, 
1771.88, 1537.5, 945.95, 1763.46, 2629.44, 2401.25, 947.2, 811.25, 669.13, 249.74, 332.98, 266.6, 531.88, 929, 1239.7, 831.3, 356, 385.35, 624, 348.5, 445.87, 301.49, 294.61, 329.35, 261.72, 480, 721.98, 1314.95, 538.75, 560.83, 695.56, 4743.72, 1718.76, 3792.76, 145.15, 3227.95, 2903.48, 1590, 853.13, 725.74, 549.36, 1250.5, 591.75, 591.75, 709.63, 381.63, 1034.25, 393.47, 912.71, 975.05, 1774.5, 638.25, 545.64, 1120, 625, 410.69, 600)), .Names = c("Area", "OPReason", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -86L))

# Create summary statistic of sum of Amount by Reason.
sums <- ddply(test,.(OPReason),summarize,tot=sum(Amount))

# Plot out above test as ordered bar chart. Running the code to geom_bar works 
# fine, but geom_text is not finding object 'Amount'.
  plot <- ggplot(test, aes(x=reorder(OPReason,Amount,function(x) -sum(x)),
                         y=(Amount/1000), fill=Area))+ 
        geom_bar(stat='identity')+
        geom_text(data=sums,stat='identity',aes(label=tot))
  plot
# This msg appears: Error in tapply(X = X, INDEX = x, FUN = FUN, ...) : 
# object 'Amount' not found
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are using another data frame for the `geom_text()`, you should provide your x and y variables for `geom_text()` and also add `inherit.aes=FALSE` to `geom_text()` to ensure that variable names defined in `ggplot()` call are ignored for `geom_text()`. Also I think you need to use `stat_summary()` to show sum of values for each `Area`.

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=reorder(OPReason,Amount,function(x) -sum(x)),
                         y=(Amount/1000), fill=Area))+ 
  stat_summary(fun.y=sum,geom="bar",position="stack")+
  geom_text(data=sums,aes(label=tot,x=OPReason,y=tot/1000),inherit.aes=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, that was easy. My confusion on this arose because I was successfully using my original code on another dataset; however I was using stat_summary rather than geom_bar, which may have been the difference? Strange. I'll have to figure out what made this work previous times...

Comment: geom_bar() worked in situation when data where in right order. Problem with geom_bar() is that you make many small bars stacked on each other but stat_summary() actually sums values.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm not very articulate in `ggplot2` yet, but generally it seems like `stat_summary` is a more concise/robust way to designate the desired visual & aesthetics, rather than geom_ types (`geom_bar`, `geom_line`, etc.)

Comment: Yes, exactly - if you need to sum values, then use stat_summary() or precompute values before plotting.